# destroy activity after opening a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am opening a fragment from activity. On opening the fragment, the activity adds at the background of the fragment. Here is a snipet of how I am opening the fragment

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                        .add(android.R.id.content, new HomeFragment()).commit();
```

**EDITTED**
Here is my home fragment xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HomeFragment">

    <!--<TextView-->
        <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
        <!--android:layout_centerInParent="true"-->
        <!--android:text="HOME"-->
        <!--android:textSize="30sp" />-->

    <!--<include layout="@layout/view_image" />-->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The above fragment is opened from within an activity. My challenge is how can I destroy the Activity after opening the fragment.

Comment: Yeah..... shown fully on the page without the activity

Comment: Have shown my home fragment layout code

Comment: which section of the activity code do you want

Comment: What do you want to achieve by destroing activity?

Comment: Destroying the Activity will also destroy the fragments, but if you want to do that from a fragment you must call getActivity().finish()